# Rails 7 + Turbo: Do not show loading state when navigating

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I have a turbo frame set up in my Rails application that the user can navigate. The problem is that when a user navigates within the frame, the turbo frame takes a few moments to update during which it shows the loading state. Now, I would prefer if that did not happen and it showed the old frame until the new frame is ready and then replaces the old frame so that the user never sees the loading state. Is that possible? I would like to do this since then the content of the frame would not "snap around" like it does right now when navigating.

Here is my (simplified) code:

index.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "posts", src: search_path do %>
  Loading results...
<% end %>
```

_posts.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "posts" do %>
  <%= link_to "Next Page", search_path(page: (params[:page]&.to_i || 0) + 1) %>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <div>
      <p><%= post.name %></p>
      <p><%= post.body %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def search
    posts = Post.all
    posts = posts.offset((params[:page]&.to_i || 0) * 50).limit(50)
    render(partial: "posts", locals: { posts: posts })
  end
  ...
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you render some posts to begin with `render @posts` inside the frame instead of showing "Loading results..." (and remove `src:`). also there are easy ways to paginate https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy

Comment: Okay, I will look into pagy, thanks! Also, thank you for the initial loading tip, however that is not my main problem. If the snapping from the frame loading happens once in the beginning it's not a problem, it's just a problem when it happens constantly when navigating. I will implement render some posts in the beginning now though, thanks!

Comment: i'm not exactly clear what other loading do you have other than the initial load. maybe i'm misremembering something, but there shouldn't be any loading state for a turbo frame after the initial load.

Comment: Hmm. I believe you are right since when I look at it again together with a sleep in the posts partial, the new partial is only shown once it is ready and there is no loading state. However, when I do this in my real app, where the partial is a lot more complex, the partial still snaps into place when loaded. This may mean that the issue is on the client side, I will have to look into that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was that I was using the Feather Icons Library and the library requires the icons to be placed in the view by using Javascript. Because of the Javascript needs a few more milliseconds after the view had been rendered, the icons would only then load in and thus change the layout of the view slightly. Thanks again for the helpful suggestions!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).